# RunOnUiThread in static method

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

How can I use RunOnUiThread in a static method within an Activity to be accessed by another class ?
In MainActivity i have a method for update listview with values from class UtilDoc.cs.
The error:

**Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Android.App.Activity.RunOnUiThread(System.Action)' (CS0120) (MyProject)**

MainActivity.cs:

```
public static void UpDateValue(string value)
{
  RunOnUiThread(() => {
          //updateListview
        });
}
```

UtilDoc.cs

```
public void SendValueListView()
{
  string value = GetValue();
  MainActivity.UpDateValue(value);
}
```

Comment: You simply can't. Not sure why you even would want to do that, care to explain, in more detail, what you want to achieve with this kind of architecture and why it is a good thing to do it this way?

Comment: @Cheesebaron In the application the user receives listview in a position of gps to move to the point received. It can also add a new point via a button (add position). So I need to update the listview.

Comment: That does not really explain the design choice you have made...

Comment: @Cheesebaron well, i have a service that connects to my server and messaging. We list these messages in listiview (containing a editview and a button for the user to send commands to the server), these commands are also placed in the same listview that receives the server command. What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't.

Instead you could (but probably shouldn't) make UpDateValue(string value) a non-static method and provide UtilDoc with a reference to MainActivity so that you can call UpDateValue.

The better solution would be to create an Adapter for the ListView and tell that to update the data.

For more information on ListView and Adapters: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/

Comment: Frank, i use a ArrayAdapter<string> for populate ListView, But I can not update the listview (even using the ArrayAdapter) by service that runs in the background.